# Why do we need to declare method arguments and return type in Functional Interface while the compiler is smart to find them from the lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I'm beginner at Lambda Expressions and I'm trying to learn them.
in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUIAvs4OEkM) (at 4:49) the teacher said:

> the Java compiler says: "Hey. if you're writing a lambda expression,
> don't tell me what the return type is. I can look at the code and
> figure it out."

ok. I'm ok with that.
But in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNE8OYBzj7E), after writing this line of code (`myLambdaFunction = () -> System.out.println("HelloWorld");`), (at 0:55) he said:

> the question that we were struggling with is what's the type of this
> variable (myLambdaFunction) ? it's a variable that contains a lambda
> expression; a lambda function.     is it a type called 'FunctionType'
> in Java 8?  this FunctionType if it existed would have had to provide
> all the inputs for what this function is going to be like. it had to
> tell what the input argument is, what the return type is. something
> like this:
>
> ```
> FunctionType<void,void> myLambdaFunction = () -> System.out.println("HelloWorld");
> ```
>
> but the Java language designers didn't really do this. they didn't
> create a new type called Functiontype. they actually said: "hey we
> have this really nice system in Java to declare functions. to declare
> methods. and that's the interface. "  so they have reused the same
> construct for declaring lambda expressions as well.

My problem is why he said:

> the type would have had to provide all the inputs for what this
> function is going to be like. it had to tell what the input argument
> is, what the return type is

Why the type should provide input arguments and the return type? we know that the compiler is smart enough to find them from the lambda expression.
from `() -> System.out.println("HelloWorld");` the java compiler can understand that we have no input arguments and our return type is void.
then why we should provide these information in the type? (I know that we provide them as signature of the single method of the Functional interface.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through those videos but I scanned the first one around the time you mentioned and I think the answer is that there are two different concerns addressed in these two videos.

The first video describes how to construct a lambda.  And the narrator goes through the process of stripping away all the unnecessary stuff from a function definition to create the lambda expression so it (the lambda) can be assigned to a variable.  This video (in the section that I watched) had nothing to say about the variable the lambda was being assigned to.

The second video (from your description) seems to address the other side of the assignment - the variable that the lambda is being assigned to.  Here you see that you need to declare the variable and it appears to be describing what is necessary to do just that.  You can't just put a name out there without declaring what that name represents.  It is a variable with a type.  What is the type of the variable.  Since `FunctionType` is a generic class it has to be provided the proper type parameters in the declaration.

I'm not a regular Java user so I don't know if Java has the equivalent of the `auto` type in C++ where the compiler can infer the type of a variable from the type of the expression used in an assignment declaration.  If so then you could probably use that as well.  If not, then you are stuck with declaring the variable (including its type) as described in the video.  But, in either case, that variable has a type.  This appears to be a description of how to determine the exact type of that variable.

And, presumably, you will need to know that type as well.  If you pass that variable as a parameter to a function then the type of the variable must be the same as (or convertible to) the type of the parameter.  Stating explicitly, at the point of declaration, what type you expect that variable to be is good code documentation.

**Edit**

After looking at the relevant section in the second video I see he is describing SAMs (interfaces with a Single Abstract Method).  The principle is the same as what I said above but the syntax is a bit different.  The compiler can check the types of the interface function as well as determine the type of the lambda expression itself and guarantee that they match when the variable is declared.